# Datagrid won't highlight

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

Very bizarre issue here: For whatever reason, my datagrid will not highlight items as I roll my mouse over them. Instead, the highlight bar just remains static on the last entry in the datagrid. I know I can still select items as I have written methods that respond to the selection. Anyone have any ideas? Here is the datagrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid x="323" y="245" width="286" dataProvider="{allBanks}"  
            id="bank" rowCount="4" >
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="bank" headerText="Bank Name"/>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some of your source? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't allBanks being refreshed in a loop?

Comment: I tested the code and it worked fine.  Can you show your CSS or any styles related to the datagrid? Something is off somewhere because if you use the same code in a blank project, it works.  Also, why are you using Datagrid for 1 column? why not use list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in `uid` attributes of data items of your data provider. If `uid`s are the same (maybe as a result of cloning of some other logic) `DataGrid`, which relies on unique `uid`, can't determine the exact item to highlight.